# SQL count on a joined table

Tags: sql, select, join, count

I've got 2 tables, 1 is `Persons` and 1 is `Relationships`.

I want to retrieve the person with the most children.

Currently I'm joining the tables like this:

```
SELECT 
   PERSONS.ID, 
   PERSONS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, 
   RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID, 
   RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION 
FROM PERSONS
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIPS ON RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID = ID 
                            AND RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION = 'child';
```

Now I'm trying to count `PERSONS.ID` and get the max, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: Can you give more info about your table and expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using group by:

`SELECT PERSONS.ID, COUNT(*) "No of Children" FROM PERSONS
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIPS ON RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID = ID 
                            AND RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION = 'child'
GROUP BY persons.id;`

Answer (score 3):

You could use partition by ...

```
SELECT PERSONS.ID, PERSONS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID, 
       RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION,
       count(*) over (partition by Persons.ID order by Persons.ID)
FROM PERSONS
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIPS ON RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID = ID AND 
                            RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION = 'child';
```

Also, you could do simple GROUP BY if you don't like partition by

```
SELECT PERSONS.ID, PERSONS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID, 
       RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION,
       COUNT(*)
FROM PERSONS
INNER JOIN RELATIONSHIPS ON RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID = ID AND 
                            RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION = 'child';
GROUP BY  PERSONS.ID, PERSONS.NATIVE_COUNTRY, RELATIONSHIPS.PERSON_ID,
          RELATIONSHIPS.RELATION
```

Also, when using joins try to use alias, it's better for readability and no reason for all upper case characters

Comment: I don't wanna open a new thread of similar question: I'm trying to retrieve the average number of children for a person in a country, for each country in the database (There is a field Persons.Country)

Comment: Add 'Country' table in this join, and instead of count just use AVG function